# Unable to pass value from one form to another - Ms access

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-forms

I have a multiple VBA forms, the first form takes user's name from a combo box and saves it in a global variable, code is below :

```
Option Compare Database
Public emplID_global

Private Sub OKLogin_Click()


 If Not IsNull(Me.Combo_emplID) Then
  emplID_global = Me.Combo_emplID.Column(1)
  DoCmd.Close
  DoCmd.OpenForm "NavFrm", acNormal
 End If
End Sub
```

Now in my other form I have a combo box in which I want to auto-populate the valueof that variable, on load of form, which i saved using previous form, below is the code :

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
 Me.AdvName = emplID_global
 Me.DataForm.Form.Recordset.MoveLast

End Sub
```

but it is not working, It is not doing anything. I want to use this kind of code in all the forms.

Can someone please suggest what is the mistake in my code, i am fairly new to VBA. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If one record on form is editable then they all are. If you want to control access to individual records probably need something like SQLServer. Securing an Access db is a common topic.

Answer (score 3):

Add a field to your underlying table for the owner of that particular record.  (I just called it `Owner`.)

Add the following code to your form:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
Owner = Environ("username")
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim editable As Boolean

if nz(Owner,"")="" then
    editable=true
else
    editable = (Environ("username") = Owner)
    End If

Form.AllowDeletions = editable
Form.AllowEdits = editable

End Sub
```

This is a fairly generic solution that does the job.  `Environ("username")` returns the user's windows username.  This is not necessarily all *that* secure.  A person could go to the *command prompt* and edit the `username` environment variable so that they appear to be another person.  This will definitely *not* keep out the NSA or anyone else with a little computer knowledge and bad intentions.  But it *will* keep the honest people honest.

Explanation:
The `BeforeInsert` runs as a new record is being saved.  In this case, it sets the record's `Owner` field to the user's Windows username.

The `OnCurrent` portion runs every time a new record is displayed.  The code will check to see if the current Windows username matches the username stored in the record's `Owner` field and set the forms `AllowEdits` and `AllowDeletions` flags accordingly.  Also, if the `Owner` field is `null` (as in the case of a new record), `editable` will be set to `true`.  If you wanted to *really* emphasize the fact that the user shouldn't be changing things, you could also enable/disable the individual text boxes...

```
TextBox1.Enabled=editable
ComboBox2.Enabled=editable
... etc.
```

Simple solution.  Keeps honest people from overwriting each others' work.  I use this approach a lot.

Comment: Nice. If you want better security without using API calls, use `CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName` instead of `Environ("username")`.

Comment: thanx @xpofer, its a very nice approach, I will try this and get back to you. You are awsome,

Comment: hey @xpofer I dont think I can prevent users from editing each others data, since I user have restricted editing in the form and its in data entry mode, It saves the form on submit button click and then requery. I have not allowed users to view data in form but I have a sub form datasheet attached through which users can view or edit the data in the table( since  I have disabled all the acces features for them)
so the question is how to let only users who own that particular entry edit or delete thier entries in subform.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be able to add the Form_Current code to your subform as well.  Should work exactly the same.  Even in a subform of continuous forms, the Form_Current event is still triggered every time you move the focus to a new row.  If your "Submit" button is on the main form, you can move the code that inserts the username to the button.  Let me know if you get this to work.  If not, we'll talk more specifics and we'll figure it out.

Comment: @xpofer, I have edited the qustion again, since people down voted the question so I was not able to ask another question, can you help me with this new scenario please